# Magento change payment information in the email templates

Tags: magento, email, templates

I have a small problem with the email templates.
In the checkout and cart pages i managed to change 'Grand Total' to 'Total'
This didn't change in the email templates though.

does anyone know how i can remove the Grand total excl VAT.
And change 'Grand Total incl Vat' to 'Total'?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The email template that includes the total is in:

```
email/order/invoice/items.phtml
```

More specifically it's this line of code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('invoice_totals')?>
```

The template for `invoice_totals` is `sales/order/totals.phtml`

The template for the Grand Total is in:

```
tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml
```

To get the grand total you can use the following code:

```
<?php $grandTotal =  Mage::getBlockSingleton('tax/checkout_grandtotal')->getTotalExclTax(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)
Do you happen to know where i can change the grand total for the admin -> Sales -> orders -> order ?